# Pandas: Search if substring contains key in dictionary, and return value

Tags: python, string, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary (key, value) and a dataframe using pandas.

```
mydict = {'KULAR LUMPUR' : 'MY',
            'SINGAPORE' : 'SG',
            'HONG KONG' : 'HK',
            'VIETNAM': 'VN'}
```

and a dataframe with column ['Address']

```
                              Address
0  234 JALAN ST KULAR LUMPUR MALAYSIA
1       123 BUILDING STREET SINGAPORE
2          67 CANNING VALE, HONG KONG
```

How do I search through the dataframe to get the value from the dictionary if substring is found in the key of the dictionary.

e.g.

```
                              Address Code
0  234 JALAN ST KULAR LUMPUR MALAYSIA   MY
1       123 BUILDING STREET SINGAPORE   SG
2          67 CANNING VALE, HONG KONG   HK
```

Comment: format your `dict` and `dataframes` properly, so we can run it directly without adding all quotes and commas.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) by `regex` with keys of dictionary with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Address': ['234 JALAN ST KULAR LUMPUR MALAYSIA', 
                               '123 BUILDING STREET SINGAPORE', 
                               '67 CANNING VALE, HONG KONG']})

print (df)
                              Address
0  234 JALAN ST KULAR LUMPUR MALAYSIA
1       123 BUILDING STREET SINGAPORE
2          67 CANNING VALE, HONG KONG

mydict = {'KULAR LUMPUR' : 'MY',
            'SINGAPORE' : 'SG',
            'HONG KONG' : 'HK',
            'VIETNAM': 'VN'}

pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in mydict.keys())
df['Code'] = df['Address'].str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False).map(mydict)

print (df)
                              Address Code
0  234 JALAN ST KULAR LUMPUR MALAYSIA   MY
1       123 BUILDING STREET SINGAPORE   SG
2          67 CANNING VALE, HONG KONG   HK
```

**Explanation**:

```
print (pat)
\bKULAR LUMPUR\b|\bSINGAPORE\b|\bHONG KONG\b|\bVIETNAM\b
```

`\b` are called word boundaries for match words between `\b`
`|` are for regex `OR`

Comment: Jezrael, can pls you add the explanation about `pat` that will help readers and me :-)

Comment: I am getting this error.
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'

Comment: @newtoCS - do you use `df['Address'].str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False).map(mydict)` ?

Comment: I have used.. and if it is KULARLUMPUR , without spacing - this answer works. However, if it is KULAR LUMPUR with spacing (2 words), the error will come up

Comment: @newtoCS - For me it working nice, there are same spaces, only one in data and in dictioanry?

Comment: @newtoCS - no idea what is problem, added sample DataFrame. It working for me nice. Can you test it if working for you? If not, what is your pandas version?